# Two images one on the other

Tags: graphics

I have two picture, one (Image 1) is the big one while the other (Image 2) is the small one that is a detail of the big one. I would like to do something like the zoom option (with `tikzpicture`) but instead to have the zoomed image image I just want to see the other image. Everything inside a figure with its caption.

I made an example in case is difficult to understand what I want to do.
[image]
`Image 1` is my main image, the cross represents the schematised detail that is explained with `Image 2`. The two images are two `.png`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting point. Now, you only need to connect the other anchors and decide the right position for the squares.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (one) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[anchor=north,draw,inner sep=0pt] (two) at ([xshift=-1cm]one.north west){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[draw] (rect) at (-1,0){};
\draw (two.south east) -- (rect.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it exist an easy way to find the right position for the small square? Like an online tool that gives the relative coordinate of the main image using just the mouse pointer?

Comment: Mouse pointer is not good since usually the result is given in pixels. If you use Gimp (free) you can create a rectangle and see its coordinates in other units. Or use Imagemagick, which is lighter.

Comment: Ok it doesn't matter, I made it in the old way. Thanks it's perfect!

Answer (score 6):

A solution using `path picture` to clip the zoom.

And as @Sigur said 'Starting point. Now, you only need to connect the other anchors and decide the right position for the' circles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption[Text for the list of figures]{Text under the figure}
        \label{fig:theReference0}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [path image/.style={path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{#1}};}}]

            \node (img) {\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}};
            \node (c1) [draw, circle, red, text width=.7cm] at (img.center) {};
            \draw [red] (c1.east) -- (img.east);
            \draw [path image=example-image-a,draw=red,thick] (img.east) circle (2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Text for the list of figures]{Text under the figure}
        \label{fig:theReference}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: + Capitalizing the "a" to emphasize magnification

Answer (score 1):

With `picture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\setlength{\unitlength}{\textwidth}%
\begin{picture}(1,0.5)%
    \put(0.3,0){\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}}%
    \put(0,0.33){\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}}%
    \put(0.0,0.33){\line(4,-1){.4}}
    \put(0.0,0.53){\line(4,-1){.4}}
    \put(0.2,0.33){\line(4,-1){.4}}
    \put(0.2,0.53){\line(4,-1){.4}}
    \put(0.4,0.23){\line(1,0){.2}}
    \put(0.4,0.43){\line(1,0){.2}}
    \put(0.4,0.23){\line(0,1){.2}}
    \put(0.6,0.23){\line(0,1){.2}}
\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share a sample code:

```
\documentclass{report}%report
% if you just want to create and use the figure in the original latex file to lower the compilation time like me, use standalone 
%\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
% 0,0 will be the distance from the inside small rectangle
\node[draw] (one) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{main_image.png}};
\node[anchor=north,draw,inner sep=0pt] (two) at ([xshift=1.55cm, yshift= -1.45cm]one.north east)
% bm: how far the zoom image should be, either west/east = right/left
{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{zoom_image.png}};
\node[draw = purple,minimum width=5.03cm,minimum height=1cm]
(rect) at (0.25,-1.45){};%(-2.2,-1.855){}; 
% draw, thick,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm
% 
\draw [purple](two.south east) -- (rect.south west);
\draw [purple](two.north west) -- (rect.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```